# automatic feed from facebook to my website

Tags: facebook-like, feed

I own the domain name stfu.com and had an idea for a website.

People on Facebook always say "stfu" in their conversations.

Is there a way to create an automatic feed that copies and pastes conversations automatically from Facebook that have the words "stfu" with atleast 5 likes from ALL Facebook accounts automatically to my website stfu.com

For example:  when anyone on Facebook uses the term "stfu" and then gets atleast 5 likes...
this conversation should automatically be copied and pasted on my website stfu.com

is this possible to do?

thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Copied and pasted - how, exactly? Do you want a live feed, through the Facebook API, of all such conversation on FB?

Comment: Yes, i want live feed from facebook to my website when anybody on Facebook says "stfu" ... i would like that conversation posted automatically to my website stfu.com
is this possible?

Comment: Have you checked through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ ?